# how to propagate to DURANDAL a click event has been generated by an external javascript framework like Googlle Charts

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

I am using DURANDAL JS to build my web application and I need to add a google chart (PieChart).  So far so good I can use 'ko.bindingHandlers' to create the binding needed to interface the chart with knockout.  Now my question is : how can I interface the events generated by the chart then propagate the event to the DURANDAL layer?  I mean if I click on the chart I would like to navigate to a specific DURANDAL view.

thanks in advance.

jm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ko.utils.registerEventHandler` to register and event handler in the `init` of your binding.

You can find a good example on [Ryan Niemeyer's blog](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/fun-with-highlighting-in-knockoutjs.html).

Take a look at how he's binding to the `mouseup` event.

Another approach you could take is to utilize Durandal's built-in pub/sub.  You could call app.trigger() inside your custom binding, and then have your viewmodel subscribe to it.  Your custom binding could send along with app.trigger() a payload appropriate to your usage scenario.